# Tooltips with GUI for system monitoring

Tags: linux, fedora, task-manager

Im newbie on linux O.S and im trying use FedoraOS 30 . I need a suggestions about tools with gui to monitor the memory, I/O, CPU's, temperature in the motherboard, cpu, kernel, networking, etc. A tool like task manager for Windows. On my Fedora am using the Gnome as interface. So there are the tools like this? I want monitor a most information possible to understand when e why my computer get so slow and in some time is needed to restart because occurs a freezy so bad wich   i can't do anything. My computer is a notebook with following specifications:

Intel Core i5-7200U 2.5GHz
NVIDIA GeForce 940MX with 2GB VRAM GDDR5
8GB DDR4 RAM
1TB HDD

Answer (score 0):

This would be more on topic for `softwarerecs.se`

That said, I really like `gkrellm` for what you are describing.  Very configurable and it reads from lower level utilities like `lmsensors`.  Right now mine is displaying activity for all 4 cores, available/used RAM and swap, disk i/o, fan speeds, mobo voltages, network traffic, date and time, uptime,  and process counts.

If you have remote machines on your LAN, etc. that you want to monitor, there is the daemon `gkrellmd` which `gkrellm` can act as a client for as well as monitoring the local machine.